# Creating new instance of the same class from within main in Java

Tags: java, object

Is it correct in Java to instantiate a new instance of a class from within the main method of that class?

I have seen this code:

```
public class MaxContiguousSum {
 public int get(int[] iArray){
  if(iArray.length==0){
   return 0;
  }

  int maxsum = iArray[0];
  int currentsum = 0;

  for(int i=0;i < iArray.length;i++){
   currentsum += iArray[i];
   if(currentsum > maxsum){
    maxsum = currentsum;
   }
   if(currentsum < 0){
    currentsum=0;
   }
  }

  return maxsum;
 }

 public static void main(String[] args) {
  int[] iarr = {-7,-6,-5,-4,-5,-6,-7};
  MaxContiguousSum maxsum = new MaxContiguousSum();
  System.out.println(maxsum.get(iarr));
 }

}
```

And it's kind of confusing to me since the main method is within the class itself, but is instantiating an object of that class. Is this correct in Java? And by correct I mean, is it a good practice?

Comment: Everything is correct in the right context. What is your exact question?

Comment: It's fine if it works and is clear. There's no particular code smell there, if that's what you are asking, at least not in your example. In larger applications I don't tend to have code like this, but for quick one-offs with single source files, it is very convenient (and to be honest, is much better practice than making everything `static` in a small program). Also, sometimes, even in larger projects, it can be useful to put a `main` in a specific class for quick tests, or for utility applications.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a bad practice, however you may want to separate your classes within the same package, or even in different packages once your code grows.

If it's for a quick test, there's absolutely nothing wrong with it.

In other words...

The `main` method is an entry point to your application.

If your application only consists of one class or a few classes, possibly within the same file, then your entry point can be a static method of (one of) your class(es).

Once you start to get package hierarchies and a lot of structured code you may want to separate your entry point from your data, presentation, resources, etc.